# Changing cell color to RGB values within Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rgb

I've essentially got 10 sets of RGB values in 30 columns (each value in their own cell) with repeated different RGB values in 8 rows below these.  What I would like to do is color the cell of 10 cells to the right of these 30 to show a visual representation of the 10 colors (based on their set of RGB values) in all 8 of these rows.  I've seen a few VBA examples out in the wild that sort of do something similar but more just on a individual set of RGB values.  I was thinking I could create function like the following but that doesn't seem to work.  Maybe a Sub routine would be required to do this but not sure where to start.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
Function RGB_Color(R As Integer, B As Integer, G As Integer)

    RGB_Color = Application.ThisCell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with this sub. It will color a range of your desire (Rc) with data from (Rs).

```
Sub ColorRGB(Rs As Range, Rc As Range)
Dim R As Long
Dim G As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim Address(1 To 3) As Long
Dim I As Integer: I = 1
For Each cell In Rs.Cells
Address(I) = cell.Value
I = I + 1
Next
R = Address(1)
G = Address(2)
B = Address(3)
Rc.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
End Sub
```

Test:

In this test, we're coloring the cell D1 with the contents from the range A1:C1.

```
Sub Test()
ColorRGB Sheet1.Range("A1:C1"), Sheet1.Range("D1")
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

The code below uses the RGBColor Sub. It will define a `lastrow` long (8 in our case) so this can basically handle more rows. Then, it will take the first vertical range of 8 cells and set it in a `Range object` called `r` only to do a `For Each` loop on it later.

With every cell in the `For Each` loop, we're going to run with another `For` loop transversely (in direction of columns). The new `For` loop will run with step of 3 calling our ColorRGB function and telling it to take in the arguments supplied below.

Given the fact that the `For` loop runs with a step of 3, we've defined a counter for the colored cells called `c` that increments itself by 1 with each step of the `For` loop (its step is egal to 3).

I hope this logic is clear. There are obviously better methods to do this.

```
Sub ColorSheet(sheetname As string)
Dim r As Range
'defining lastrow which is 8
Dim lastrow As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname)
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = .Range("A1", "A" & lastrow)
End With
Dim C As Integer: C = 30
For Each cell In r.Cells
For I = 1 To 30 Step 3
ColorRGB ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range(cell.Offset(0, I - 1).Address(0, 0), cell.Offset(0, I + 1).Address(0, 0)), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range(cell.Offset(0, C).Address(0, 0))
C = C + 1
Next I
C = 30
Next
End Sub
```

This final sub will color the sheet name you provide it with.

```
Sub Test
ColorSheet("Sheet3")
'And so on...
End Sub
```

If your sheets are named like SheetX

```
    Sub Test
    Dim I as Integer
    For I = 1 to 20
    ColorSheet("Sheet"&I)
    Next I
    End Sub
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jlili.  That kind of gets me part way there but since the RGB values are within the spreadsheet, I need a way for the sub routine to read those in from the spreadsheet vs. manually typing them.  Any tips on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can create three longs, R, G, B and then fill them with the values for from your range. Just don't forget to use `CLong` to convert the values into longs. Hold on a sec let do that for you.

Comment: @wilbev if you have any questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Jlili.  Thank you so much.  I can get this to work on only a single worksheet.  I didn't say state this but I need to run this on over 20 worksheets.  The strangest thing about this, if I copy the exact data to a new worksheet, the code simply does nothing, like it only recognizes the first sheet created no matter what I rename it too.  Any guesses what may be going on there?

Comment: Done. You can color by providing sheetname to the test sub! Just tick this answer if it does the job! Many thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again Jlili.  That did the trick.  I hate to get greedy but I have one last item to work out.  As I go down from the top row, 1 set of RGB values drop off, so instead of starting in A1, the next row starts in D2, row after that G3, etc.  Is there way I could add 3 each time for the next row it starts on?

Comment: Yes. Simply create Sub that will uncolor cells using the same logic. I'm falling asleep man :)

Answer (score 0):

Yours doesn't work because you're passing RGB_Color(R,B,G) to RGB(R,G,B)